# D3: Order grouped column chart

Tags: d3.js

Take [this simple grouped column chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051). The data values are passed in this format:

```
{
    "Group1": [group1_subvalue1, group1_subvalue2.....],
    "Group2": [group2_subvalue1, group2_subvalue2.....],
    ....
}
```

I'd like to sort each group individually, i.e.: for each state, order the columns from taller to narrower. But I'm unable to find a way to do it. In the given example, the array for each group must be in the same order (first people under 5 y.o, 5 to 13 after that, and so on), so I don't know how to face the problem.

Comment: .filter(function(d){ //code here yo you wish to filter by;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show how to sort each group individually, I took [Mike Bostock's example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051)  to adjusted it accordingly.
You have to do the following things:

1. You sort the within-group categories (in the example it's the d.ages Array)

   ```
   d.ages.sort(function(a, b) { return d3.ascending(a.value, b.value); });
   ```
2. x1 is your scale for the within group categories. Instead of mapping the categories to the same relative position, you just map the index of your sorted array to the x position. d3.range() creates an array which is your domain.

   ```
   x1.domain(d3.range(0, data[0].ages.length)).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
   ```
3. When you draw, you just call the index instead of the category

   ```
   .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x1(i); })
   ```

The full working example is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/EE2dev/af14387f43b5f332e360).
I have also added how to sort the groups.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I was asking for, thank you!